# Displaying the number of records to display (pagination) in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table with pagination in my Vue project. I have those fields:

- Field `tableItemsPerPage` contains the number of items to show per page (10, 25, 50, 100).
- Field `tableCrrentPage` contains the current page number.
- Field `items` contains the items (array).

I want to display the following message:

```
Showing 1 to 10 out of 1500 records.
Showing 11 to 20 out of 1500 records.
...
```

The code:

```
getRecordsText: function() {
    var records_amount = this.items.length;
    var start = this.tableCrrentPage;
    var end = this.tableCrrentPage;
    return start + " to " + end + " out of " + records_amount + " records";
}
```

I'm not sure how to calculate `start` and `end` based on those fields. Is there a formula I could construct that can show the messages?

Comment: Try `ag-grid-vue` it will give you lot of grid features which take minimal time to implement with minimal code. It's just a suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See table below

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 a b c
```

here `tableItemsPerPage = 4`

assuming `tableCrrentPage` is initially `0`

you get

`{ start, end } = { start: (tableCrrentPage * 4 ) + 1, end: (tableCrrentPage * 4 ) + 4 }`

```js
x= (p, n) => ({ start: (p * n) + 1, end: (p * n) + n })
console.log('10 items per page')
console.log(x(0, 10))
console.log(x(1, 10))
console.log(x(2, 10))
console.log('20 items per page')
console.log(x(0, 20))
console.log(x(1, 20))
console.log(x(2, 20))
```